# Android updating a notification and detecting when it no longer exists

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am able to create notifications.  Currently when a user gets a friend request, it says "New friend request from someUsername".  However, if the user receives multiple friend requests, I want to update the text to say "New friend requests."

From my understanding, I just have to change the text using the same Builder object I used to create the initial notification.

My idea was to create a HashMap mapping all the IDs used in NotificationManager's `notify( int id, Builder builder )` to the Builder objects.

When a notification is clicked, the notification disappears (due to my use of `setAutoCancel(true)` ), however, I don't know how to detect this so I can remove the Builder object from the HashMap as well.

The reason I would like to remove the Builder object is because when the HashMap's `get(id)` method returns `null`, I'll know to display "New friend request from " instead of "New friend requests".

If my algorithm is over-complicated, by all means correct me.  Otherwise, how can I detect when a notification is canceled?

Side note: I plan on doing this same thing for messages and possibly other kinds of notifications.

In case it's needed, this is my function that creates the notifications (the id is hardcoded for now):

```
private void triggerNotification(String content, Context context) {

    Log.i("Thread", "notification triggered");

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Anime Chatter")
            .setContentText( content );

    builder.setAutoCancel( true );

    Intent i = new Intent(context, Friends.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );

    mNotificationManager.notify( 1010, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: You dont need the same builder object, only the same ID, it will replace the notification.

Comment: @jvrodrigues Correct, it will `replace` it if I use the same ID.  But then how would I know to set the text to "New friend request from username" vs "New friend requests" ? I need a way of knowing whether a notification currently exists with the ID or not.

Comment: By persisting the state of the notification somewhere.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Can you give a little more detail on what you mean by that? It's my first time working notifications.  I posted my notificaiton function above to give a better idea of what I'm aware of.

Comment: Just save somewhere that a notification is displayed and then use that information to decide which text to put in the notification.

Comment: @XaverKapeller That's the idea behind my HashMap. But how do I detect when the notification is clicked so I know to reset the text for the next notification?

Comment: That should be easy because you have to display the friend requests in your app hence you can remove the notifications for those friend requests which have been viewed in your app.

Answer (score 1):

The most solid way to go at this is to create a dedicated table to deal with notifications.

That may be too much work, but it's how the biggest apps deal with notifications - which has been seen and which hasn't etc.

For a more simple approach just add some code in your activity, when dealing with the intent, that tracks the last notification clicked in a persistent way (SharedPrefs?) so that whatever controller is dispatching the notifications knows if there should be more than one notification to be seen or not (for example if the user dismisses a notification without clicking on it, there is still more than one friend request he doesnt know about). This controller should also keep track of the last sent notification (SharedPrefs again). This way when the controller dispatches the notification it can compare the last sent and the last clicked and see if there is only one, or several.

Seems pretty straight forward to me. Can help you with code if needed.

Comment: How can I know the id of the last clicked notification though? I just realized I can add the id of the notification as an extra to the intent, but I think that approach isn't the greatest since every activity I jump to from clicking a notification would have to deal with calling some function in my Notifications class to remove the Builder from the hashmap. Was this what you had in mind?

Comment: You won't need the hashmap anymore. Just put some unique extra on the intent, like the name of the friend or the id of the friend (you can add an extra field to your triggerNotification method with whatever unique ID you want) and store that id onNewIntent - this way you know if it was clicked or not.  Also important to store the last sent whenever you notify, so you can compare the last sent and last clicked.

Comment: Gave you an upvote for now.  Going to wait a bit to see if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is Notification.Builder#setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent).

The pending intent you set here (you should wrap a Broadcast Intent) will be fired when the notification is canceled by the user. You can respond to the broadcast and update your persistent storage (db, shared prefs, whatever) where you're keeping track of active notifications to determine what you should show when the next one comes in.